# In C add up 1/2 + 2/3 +...+ 18/19 + 19/20

Tags: c

Pretty much I am trying to do 1/2 + 2/3 +...+ 18/19 + 19/20 in C and here's my code:

Version 1:

```
int main(){
    double i,j,sum;

    for(i=1,j=2,sum=0; i<=19 && j<=20; i++, j++)
        sum+=i/j;
    printf("%f\n",sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Version 1 output: 
16.402260

version 2:

```
int main(){
    double i,j,sum;

    for(i=1,j=2,sum=0; i<=19 && j<=20; sum+=i/j, i++, j++)
        printf("%f\n",sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Version 2 output:

```
0.000000
0.500000
1.166667
1.916667
2.716667
3.550000
4.407143
5.282143
6.171032
7.071032
7.980123
8.896789
9.819866
10.748438
11.681771
12.619271
13.560447
14.504892
15.452260
```

Version 3:

```
int main(){
    double i,j,sum;

    for(i=1,j=2,sum=0; i<=19 && j<=20; sum+=i/j, i++, j++)
        ;
    printf("%f\n",sum);

    return 0;
}
```

version 3 output:

16.402260

I am confused as to why version 1 & 3 works where as version 2 does not, since version 2 and version 3 are very similar except for that fact that version 3's for loop contains and empty body where as version 2 does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's due to the way how the compiler translates the `for` loop:

```
 for (i=1, j=2, sum=0; i <= 19 && j <= 20; i++, j++) { /* code */ }
```

i.e.

```
 for (/* init */; /* condition */; /* increment*/) { /* code */ }
```

... is executed as ...

```
i=1, j=2, sum = 0; /* init */
while (i <= 19 && j <= 20) { /* condition */
  /* code */

  i++, j++;  /* increment */
}
```

So in version two, `sum` in `printf` doesn't have the latest value yet:

```
i=1, j=2, sum = 0; /* init */
while (i <= 19 && j <= 20) { /* condition */
  /* code */

  sum += i/j, i++, j++; /* increment */
}
```

... because `sum` is part of the increment.

Cheers!

Comment: Oh okay, got it. Thanks Trinimon! =D By the way, your explanation was awesome!!

Answer (score 4):

You're forgetting brackets.

```
for(i=1,j=2,sum=0; i<=19 && j<=20; i++, j++){
    sum+=i/j;
    printf("%f\n",sum);
}
```

In C/C++, you can have a two-line for loop (or a two-line if statement), like so:

```
for()
  line to execute
```

And it is interpreted by the compiler as

```
for()
{
    line to execute
}
```

However, this:

```
for()
line to execute
another line to execute
```

Will be seen by the compiler like this:

```
for()
{
line to execute
}
another line to execute
```

Answer (score 2):

Case 1:

```
for(i=1,j=2,sum=0; i<=19 && j<=20; i++, j++)
        sum+=i/j;
        printf("%f\n",sum);
```

is being interpreted as

```
for(i=1,j=2,sum=0; i<=19 && j<=20; i++, j++)
        sum+=i/j;
printf("%f\n",sum);
```

by the compiler. - printf executes only once

Case 3:

```
 for(i=1,j=2,sum=0; i<=19 && j<=20; sum+=i/j, i++, j++)
   ;
 printf("%f\n",sum);
```

printf executes after the whole loops has executed.

If you want the same result in case 2:

```
for(i=1,j=2,sum=0; i<=19 && j<=20; sum+=i/j, i++, j++)
    ; /*let the loop complete, and then printf*/
    printf("%f\n",sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

In version 2 you are printing the output and n-1 rather that n.

You need to print 'sum' after the loop has finished.

```
int main() {
  double i,j,sum;

  for(i=1,j=2,sum=0; i<=19 && j<=20; sum+=i/j, i++, j++) printf("%f\n",sum);

  printf("%f\n",sum);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
    sum += i/j
```

is being executed after the last printf.